# How can I use a search edittext in a listview

Tags: android, listview

HelloI added a search edittext to my fragment but i got this error cannot resolve method getFilter()
How can I use it to search in a listview like this? How I can add the icon in the edittext
By clicking in a letter, only the items beginning by this letter should be displayed

[Search edittext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThlwF.png)

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user, container, false);
listView  = (ListView)   rootview.findViewById(R.id.listView);
inputSearch  = (EditText)   rootview.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
getJSON();
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
UserFragment.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
}
                @Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                              int arg3) {
                }
                @Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                }
            });
return rootview;
        }
private void Display(){
JSONObject jsonObject = null;
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
try {
jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
 for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
String name = jo.getString("Nom");
String email = jo.getString("Email");
String login = jo.getString("Login");
HashMap<String,String> users= new HashMap<>();
users.put("name",name);
users.put("email",email);
users.put("login",login);
list.add(users);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    getActivity(), list, R.layout.list_row,
                    new String[]{"name","email"},
                    new int[]{R.id.nom, R.id.email2});
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

xml code
How I can add the icon to the edittext

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- Editext for Search -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search products.."
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

I need your help
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
android:drawableEnd="@drawable/view"
```

to add icon in your edittext.

You can search you listview by adding TextView.OnEditorActionListener on your edittext.
Example:
myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        // Do some stuff
    }
});

Comment: Can you explain more this method because I tried to implement it in my code. It doesn't work. By clicking in a letter, only the items beginning by this letter should be displayed